# SVG in img fix for IE breaks Chrome

Tags: html, css, svg

So I made an SVG for a very svg-friendly-design logo in my recent website. More as a "ah this is cool" than an absolute necessity, but now that it's not working I'm obsessed.

I dropped it in an `<img />` tag, sized it up as I like, and bam sweet logo, used in different sizes in a couple of places, scales beautifully. Ah the miracles of modern web. Remember .PNG fixes? We have come a long way in a few short years. I'm so happy we no longer have to deal with that archaic IE bullsh...

Oh, you've got to be kidding me!

[image]

So apparently IE gets funky. Alright, google this thing. "Remove height and width attributes." Fantastic, do that...

Chrome starts having the same issue with the modified file. Argh.

What am I doing wrong?

```html
<svg width="264" height="264" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
 
     <g>
      <title>background</title>
      <rect x="-1" y="-1" width="266" height="266" id="canvas_background" fill="none"/>
      <g id="canvasGrid" display="none">
       <rect id="svg_1" width="100%" height="100%" x="0" y="0" stroke-width="0" fill="url(#gridpattern)"/>
      </g>
     </g>
     <g>
      <title>Layer 1</title>
      <ellipse fill="#000000" stroke-width="0" cx="132.081358" cy="132.179138" id="svg_3" rx="132" ry="132" stroke="#fff"/>
      <ellipse fill="#000000" stroke="#fff" stroke-width="6" cx="132.081346" cy="132.17914" id="svg_5" rx="126" ry="126"/>
      <ellipse fill="#000000" stroke="#fff" stroke-width="7" cx="132.081365" cy="213.774884" id="svg_13" rx="44" ry="44"/>
      <line fill="none" stroke-width="7" stroke-opacity="null" fill-opacity="null" x1="12.496805" y1="168.812302" x2="251.665903" y2="168.812302" id="svg_24" stroke-linejoin="null" stroke-linecap="null" stroke="#fff"/>
      <ellipse fill="#d80202" stroke="#fff" stroke-width="7" cx="132.081369" cy="50.410766" id="svg_6" rx="44" ry="44"/>
      <line fill="none" stroke="#fff" stroke-width="7" stroke-opacity="null" fill-opacity="null" x1="132.08135" y1="95.543239" x2="132.08135" y2="166.831116" id="svg_26" stroke-linejoin="null" stroke-linecap="null"/>
     </g>
    </svg>
```

Comment: So are you trying to resize the SVG and keep it responsive?

Comment: @Adam I have the .svg file saved as an asset on the server and am serving it up in an `<img src="myimg.svg" />` tag, trying to treat it as normal image asset. But yes, resize it and keep it responsive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try use one of these SVG's and adjust the to make it responsive remove the `height` and `width` attrubite from the `<svg>` tag.

The first one has the style inline and the second has it in `<style>` tag.

code:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 264 264" style="enable-background:new 0 0 264 264;" xml:space="preserve" width="100" height="100">
<g>
 <title>background</title>
 <rect id="canvas_background" x="-1" y="-1" style="fill:none;" width="266" height="266"/>
 <g id="canvasGrid" style="display:none;">
  <rect id="svg_1" style="display:inline;fill:none;" width="264" height="264"/>
 </g>
</g>
<g>
 <title>Layer 1</title>
 <ellipse id="svg_3" cx="132.1" cy="132.2" rx="132" ry="132"/>
 <ellipse id="svg_5" style="stroke:#FFFFFF;stroke-width:6;" cx="132.1" cy="132.2" rx="126" ry="126"/>
 <ellipse id="svg_13" style="stroke:#FFFFFF;stroke-width:7;" cx="132.1" cy="213.8" rx="44" ry="44"/>
 <line id="svg_24" style="fill:none;stroke:#FFFFFF;stroke-width:7;" x1="12.5" y1="168.8" x2="251.7" y2="168.8"/>
 <ellipse id="svg_6" style="fill:#D80202;stroke:#FFFFFF;stroke-width:7;" cx="132.1" cy="50.4" rx="44" ry="44"/>
 <line id="svg_26" style="fill:none;stroke:#FFFFFF;stroke-width:7;" x1="132.1" y1="95.5" x2="132.1" y2="166.8"/>
</g>
</svg>

<br />
<br />

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 264 264" style="enable-background:new 0 0 264 264;" xml:space="preserve" width="100" height="100">
<style type="text/css">
 .st0{fill:none;}
 .st1{display:none;}
 .st2{display:inline;fill:none;}
 .st3{stroke:#FFFFFF;stroke-width:6;}
 .st4{stroke:#FFFFFF;stroke-width:7;}
 .st5{fill:none;stroke:#FFFFFF;stroke-width:7;}
 .st6{fill:#D80202;stroke:#FFFFFF;stroke-width:7;}
</style>
<g>
 <rect id="canvas_background" x="-1" y="-1" class="st0" width="266" height="266"/>
 <g id="canvasGrid" class="st1">
  <rect id="svg_1" class="st2" width="264" height="264"/>
 </g>
</g>
<g>
 <ellipse id="svg_3" cx="132.1" cy="132.2" rx="132" ry="132"/>
 <ellipse id="svg_5" class="st3" cx="132.1" cy="132.2" rx="126" ry="126"/>
 <ellipse id="svg_13" class="st4" cx="132.1" cy="213.8" rx="44" ry="44"/>
 <line id="svg_24" class="st5" x1="12.5" y1="168.8" x2="251.7" y2="168.8"/>
 <ellipse id="svg_6" class="st6" cx="132.1" cy="50.4" rx="44" ry="44"/>
 <line id="svg_26" class="st5" x1="132.1" y1="95.5" x2="132.1" y2="166.8"/>
</g>
</svg>
```